# hover() event handlers not respecting dynamically changed classes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, hover

This is my code:

```
<li class="dropdown">
    ...
</li>
```

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(".navbar").offset().top > 70) {
        $(".dropdown").addClass("dropdown-collapse").removeClass("dropdown");
    } else {
        $(".dropdown-collapse").addClass("dropdown").removeClass("dropdown-collapse");
    }
});

$(".dropdown-collapse").hover(
    function() { $(this).addClass('open') },
    function() { $(this).removeClass('open') }
);
```

When the page load at first time the class for `<li>` is still dropdown and when the page scrolled bellow 70px the class replace with dropdown-collapse. The problem is my hover function doesn't work when the class dropdown replaced with dropdown-class. Please help me guys, thank you.

Comment: The `.hover` method is actually deprecated.

Comment: so what I have to use? @PraveenKumar

Comment: `mouseenter`, `mouseleave`?

Comment: thanks, man @PraveenKumar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is due to the fact that you attach the hover event handlers on load of the page. The change in the classes on the element has no effect on any event handlers that were already bound. To do what you need to would have to use a delegated event handler, like this:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var offsetTop = $(".navbar").offset().top;
    $(".dropdown, .dropdown-collapse")
        .toggleClass("dropdown-collapse", offsetTop > 70)
        .toggleClass("dropdown", offsetTop <= 70)
});

$(document).on('mouseenter', '.dropdown-collapse', function() {    
    $(this).addClass('open');
}).on('mouseleave', '.dropdown-collapse', function() {
    $(this).removeClass('open');
});
```

Note that you could simplify the class switching logic by leaving the `.dropdown` class on the element permanently and simply switching the behaviour dependant on if the `.dropdown-collapse` class is present.

Comment: I haven't verified whether that works, but +1 for teaching me a new way to use `.toggleClass()`.